# How to type every attribute of an object as string except one?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would love to do thefollowing in typescript, where my object can accept any attribute as string, but when `specialCase` attribute is used it should be an int[]. How do i do that?

```js
interface MyObject {
  nodeName: string;
  props: {
    [x: string]: string;
    specialCase: int[];
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this directly, as the index signature `[x: string]: string;` enforces, that every property key has a compatible `string` value type. Easiest is probably to separate the index signature from explicit properties here:

```
interface MyObject2 {
  nodeName: string;
  props: {
    strings: { [x: string]: string }
    specialCase: number[];
  };
}
```

If you keep everything in `props`, the signature property value type has to be widened then and some narrowing would be necessary ([here is a sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwFgAoZZEAewBMIA5OAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwDcFKgAcoNUV05lKVZAG0AHpx58Q-ALqreA5AB9qAVxbZoCzcLlUuogsDgAbAMJwuHY6fOWRyAL5WfhQUDAiOcFAoCDQgPMg0eJwYOPiEFAm4AHTiklyZtvZOru7IAPSlnmZQFul42RJSCgBEMDQ0TZplFWp6hiAmVTXkbu5QYADKuhoAFBn1uc2t7ZoAlF3cU-zB5DBGIITAMcgj0BOb09LHIOgrOur8JL7AMMjTYOh2NC9cyACEALz-ZBNHoaJprMAACwkAHdqBA4QBRKASKDTFa%20SJgIxQEDcChBcgUUCQWCIFDJPAEMAAJkecloDGYbDuAisYgal1k8g29y5ihUvIE2iFGn8vhsdgQDhcbg8-S81R8cgCBKAA)):

```
declare const obj: MyObject

obj.props.specialCase // number[]
obj.props["foo"] // string | number[]
assertString(obj.props["foo"]) // string

function assertString(s: any): string {
  if (typeof s !== "string") throw new Error()
  return s
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can do this to type every property of an object as a string or a certain type expect one or more.

```js
interface MyObject {
  nodeName: string;
  props: {
    specialCase: int[];
  } & {
    [x: string]: string;
  };
}
```